# Can I mix C and C++ in a single program

Tags: c++, c

can i write code with mixing of c and c++ header file in a programming language?
SUPPOSE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   cout <<"Hello world"; << endl;
   printf("",);
}
```

Comment: Yes you can make a single program that uses `c` and `c++` and several other languages. This can be compiled into a single executable.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: This really depends.  A good chunk of C++ code wont compile as C but a lot of C code is valid C++ code.

Comment: No, everything the `C++` compiler sees must be valid `C++` (regardless if it is also valid `C`). This sometimes means `C` libraries need to have special `C++` versions of their headers written. However most `C` libraries have `C++` friendly headers so you don't need to think about it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can

```
/* code.cc */
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world" << endl;
   printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

However, you need to use c++ to compile the code

```
c++ -o code code.cc
./code
Hello world
Hello world
```

**In case described by *François* you need to go slightly different way**

```
/* code_c.h */
extern "C" {
  void printMessage();
}
```

Code that needs to be compiled using C

```
/* code_c.c */
#include <stdio.h>

void printMessage() {
  printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

C++ code

```
/* code.cc */
#include <iostream>
#include "code_c.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world" << endl;
   printMessage();
}
```

Gluing all together

```
cc -c code_c.c
c++ -c code.cc
c++ -o code code.o code_c.o
./code
Hello world
Hello world!
```

***Crazy mode [on]***

In fact, you can even "mix" C++ with "bash" ;)

**code_c.c**

```
echo =1/*"beat that ;)" | tail -c13
#*/;int fun(){return printf("beat that ;)\n");}
```

**code.cc**

```
extern "C" int fun();

int main() { return fun(); }
```

**compilation and execution**

```
> c++ -c code.cc
> cc -c code_c.c
> c++ -o code code.o code_c.o
> ./code
beat that ;)
> bash ./code_c.c
beat that ;)
```

***Crazy mode [off]***

Comment: It's important to mention not all c is valid c++. So you can't mix *all* legal c code with c++ code.

Comment: Sure, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is not a mix of C and C++ code. It's C++ code with some elements written using C-style coding, but not  actual C language.

You cannot mix C and C++ in a single source file. You can combine C and C++ files in the same program, but each source file must be in one language.

A header file can be written such that the code it contains can be used as both C and C++ code. When included in a C fie it is treated as C and when included in C++ file it is treated as C++. Most headers of C libraries are written this way today. One must do some (small) extra work on a C header towards C++ compatibility. A C header that ignores existence of C++ is likely to be incompatible with C++.

Comment: I want to add header file in a program and use both of their library functions in a program. I tried it in code blocks and that was run without any error.

Comment: @MehediAbdullah: this doesn't contradict the answer by n.m., which is quite right.

Comment: @MehediAbdullah see update